# An explicit form of an isomorphism $\operatorname{End}(V^* \otimes V) \simeq \operatorname{End}(\operatorname{End}(V))$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, $A: V^* \to V^*$ and $B: V \to V$ are linear maps. We know that there is an isomorphism $V^* \otimes V \simeq \operatorname{End}(V)$, so operator $A \otimes B$ induces a map $\operatorname{End}(V) \to \operatorname{End}(V)$. How to find out the explicit form of this operator?

Comment: That depends on what exactly you mean by the "explicit form"

Comment: @BenGrossmann, knowing matrices of $A$ and $B$ in standart basis. Or for example we have operator $e^{- \mathrm{i} \tau_0 H} \otimes e^{\mathrm{i} \tau_1 H}: \mathcal{H}^* \otimes \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}^* \otimes \mathcal{H}$ and want to know it's view as operator $\operatorname{End}(\mathcal{H}) \to \operatorname{End}(\mathcal{H})$.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the action of $A \otimes B$ on $\operatorname{End}(V)$, it suffices to determine its action on the rank-1 linear maps and extend by linearity. Every rank-1 linear map in $\operatorname{End}(V)$ can be written in the form $vf$ (my shorthand for the map $[vf](x) = f(x)v$) for some $v \in V,f \in V^*$. The canonical isomorphism between $\operatorname{End}(V)$ and $V^* \otimes V$ maps $vf$ to $f \otimes v$.

Let $\Phi:\operatorname{End}(V) \to V^* \otimes V$ denote this canonical map
and let $\alpha$ denote the map induced by $A \otimes B$ on $\operatorname{End}(V)$, so that $\alpha = \Phi^{-1} \circ (A \otimes B) \circ \Phi$. We find that
$$
\alpha(vf) = \Phi^{-1}(A \otimes B)\Phi(vf) = \Phi^{-1}((Af) \otimes (Bv)) = (Bv)(Af).
$$
For an arbitrary element $\tau = \sum_i v_i f_i$, we thus have $\alpha(\tau) = \sum_i (Bv_i)(Af_i)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!